# How do you maintain a community change log?

Tags: php, bug-tracking, changelog

I'm looking for a change log / features request program my client can use to see where I am at with the development. Trac looks sexy (http://trac.edgewall.org/) but too complex for what I need.

Very simply, the client needs to be able to order tasks and for us to be able to sort them and keep a record of everything that is going on.

We could update a static file or something, but that seems a bit err time consuming and not systematic enough.

What do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use Trac even for a small project since it allows you to disable most of the advanced features if you don't need them.

First, whole pages aren't shown at all if you remove a user's permission to view them. So if you e.g. don't like the "Roadmap" page, just get rid of it. There is a whole list of possible permissions in the [trac help](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPermissions).

Second, Trac even allows removing ticket fields like priorities, resolutions, severities by just deleting all possible options for them in the administration panel.

Using these tricks, you can simplify your Trac a lot but still keep the usefull stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Basecamp is a pretty slick project management solution: http://basecamphq.com

I've used this or trac depending on the project.  My 2 cents :)

Answer (score 1):

As a bug-tracker, I am using [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) :

- it is not too hard to use (our clients are using it OK, even if they are not programmers)
- it does the job ; tracking bugs, at least, with what functionnalities you could expect
- it is written in PHP, which is great if you are yourself working with PHP : it means you already have servers that can host it, and that you will know how to solve problems if you encounter some (that's one of my problems with Trac : I don't know anything about Python, to, when there's a problem, I'l literally stuck... )
- also, if you take a look at their [blog](http://www.mantisbt.org/blog/), you will notice there have been some new versions this years, which means it's still under development *(which is better than using an old tool noone cares about anymore ^^ )*

There's a [demo available](http://www.mantisbt.org/demo/my_view_page.php), btw.